# Autohotkey to put the selected text in smart quotes

Tags: autohotkey

I need an Autohotkey script that puts the selected text in these opening and closing quotation marks:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201e/index.htm - for the opening quote
and
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm - for the closing quote

So, I can select a text, press the hotkey and the text is quotes like this:

„test text“

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f1::
saved := clipboardall ; save clipboard contents
Send, ^x ; cut
Send, „%clipboard%“ ; send clipboard content with your characters around it
clipboard := saved ; restore clipboard
saved := "" ; clear saved
Return
```

If that doesn't work you can put the code in brackets:

```
f2::
saved := clipboardall
Send, ^x
Send, {U+201E}%clipboard%{U+201C}
clipboard := saved
saved := ""
Return
```

Comment: I've tested your script and it inserts unrecognized characters instead of quotes: �test text�

Comment: I tested it in notepad. Please try it in notepad, and also tell me what program(s) you intend on using it in.

Comment: Isn't your script for clipboard text?